# Java DatabaseMetaData

Tags: java, jdbc

I am starter and i want to know how to find a specific column is a FOREIGN KEY column in the database.

what i am doing is.....

I am getting a connection object from a specific data source. Using this connection object i am trying to get all the metadata of that specific datasource using DatabaseMetadata. I worked on getColumns, getPrimarykeys etc. But now i know what the tablename is what the column name is in that specific table. I want to know is that column a FORIGEN KEY column are not.

For example if i know column name i can know if that column is a PRIMARY KEY column are not in the same way i need it for a FOREGIN KEY.

Can some one help me in this

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 3):

have a look at the [getExportedKeys](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [getImportedKeys](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getImportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods. They should tell you what you want to know in a round about way...